# while_loop error in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, while-loop, python-3.5

I tried to use **while_loop** in **Tensorflow**, but when I try to return the target **output** from callable in while loop, it gives me an error because the shape is increased every time.

The output should be contains (0 or 1) values based on **data** value  (input array). If **data** value is large than 5 return **1** else return **0**. The returned value must be added into **output**

This is the code::

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = np.random.randint(10, size=(30))
data = tf.constant(data, dtype= tf.float32)

global output
output= tf.constant([], dtype= tf.float32)
i = tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i: tf.less(i, 30)


def b(i):
   i= tf.add(i,1)
   cond= tf.cond(tf.greater(data[i-1], tf.constant(5.)), lambda: tf.constant(1.0), lambda: tf.constant([0.0]))
   output =tf.expand_dims(cond, axis = i-1)
   return i, output

r,out = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
print(out)
sess=  tf.Session()
sess.run(out)
```

The error::

> r, out = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i])
>
> ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements.
>
> First structure (1 elements): [tf.Tensor 'while/Identity:0' shape=()
>   dtype=int32]
>
> Second structure (2 elements): [tf.Tensor 'while/Add:0' shape=()
>   dtype=int32, tf.Tensor 'while/ExpandDims:0' shape=unknown
>   dtype=float32>]

I use **tensorflow-1.1.3** and **python-3.5**

How can I change my code to gives me the target result?

**EDIT::**

I edit the code based on @mrry answer, but I still have an issue that the output is incorrect answer
the output is numbers summation

```
a = tf.ones([10,4])
print(a)
a = tf.reduce_sum(a, axis = 1)
i =tf.constant(0)
c = lambda i, _:tf.less(i,10)

def Smooth(x):
   return tf.add(x,2)

summ = tf.constant(0.)
def b(i,_):
   global summ
   summ = tf.add(summ, tf.cast(Smooth(a[i]), tf.float32))
   i= tf.add(i,1)
   return i, summ

r, smooth_l1 = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i, smooth_l1])

print(smooth_l1)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(smooth_l1))
```

the out put is **6.0** (wrong).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) function requires that the following four lists have the same length, and the same type for each element:

- The list of arguments to the `cond` function (`c` in this case).
- The list of arguments to the `body` function (`b` in this case).
- The list of return values from the `body` function.
- The list of `loop_vars` representing the loop variables.

Therefore, if your loop body has two outputs, you must add a corresponding argument to `b` and `c`, and a corresponding element to `loop_vars`:

```
c = lambda i, _: tf.less(i, 30)

def b(i, _):
  i = tf.add(i, 1)
  cond = tf.cond(tf.greater(data[i-1], tf.constant(5.)),
                 lambda: tf.constant(1.0),
                 lambda: tf.constant([0.0]))

  # NOTE: This line fails with a shape error, because the output of `cond` has
  # a rank of either 0 or 1, but axis may be as large as 28.
  output = tf.expand_dims(cond, axis=i-1)
  return i, output

# NOTE: Use a shapeless `tf.placeholder_with_default()` because the shape
# of the output will vary from one iteration to the next.
r, out = tf.while_loop(c, b, [i, tf.placeholder_with_default(0., None)])
```

As noted in the comments, the body of the loop (specifically the call to `tf.expand_dims()`) seems to be incorrect and this program won't work as-is, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I edit the code to make the output be a result of numbers summation. and I get no syntax error, but the output is not the correct answer. I do not know why that happened. I will edit my question based on your answer here

Comment: What's the expected answer for your code? The `global summ` and ignoring the second body argument is suspicious: you probably want to pass `0.` as the initial value for the second loop variable, and use the second body argument instead of the `global summ` as the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error:
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same number of elements.

If you see it in a while_loop, that means your inputs and outputs out of the while loop have different shapes.

I solved it by making sure that I return the same structure of loop_vars from my while loop function, the condition function must also accept same loop vars.

Here is an example code

```py
        loop_vars = [i, loss, batch_size, smaller_str_lens]
        def condition(*loop_vars):
            i = loop_vars[0]
            batch_size = loop_vars[2]
            return tf.less(i, batch_size)

        def body(*loop_vars):
            i, loss, batch_size, smaller_str_lens = loop_vars
            tf.print("The loop passed here")
           ## logic here
            i = tf.add(i, 1)

            return i, loss, batch_size, smaller_str_lens
            
        loss = tf.while_loop(condition, compare_strings, loop_vars)[1]
```

The body func must return loop vars, and the condition func must accept loop vars