# how to reshape text data to be suitable for LSTM model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, autoencoder

**Update1:**

The code Im referring is exactly the code in the book which you can find it [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/Chapter07/sent-thoughts-rnn.py).

The only thing is that I don't want to have `embed_size` in the decoder part. That's why I think I don't need to have embedding layer at all because If I put embedding layer, I need to have `embed_size` in the decoder part(please correct me if Im wrong).

Overall, Im trying to adopt the same code without using the embedding layer, because I need o have `vocab_size` in the decoder part.

I think the suggestion provided in the comment could be correct (`using one_hot_encoding`) how ever I faced with this error:

When I did `one_hot_encoding`:

```
tf.keras.backend.one_hot(indices=sent_wids, classes=vocab_size)
```

I received this error:

`in check_num_samples
    you should specify the  + steps_name +  argument 
ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the steps_per_epoch argument (instead of the batch_size argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data)`

The way that I have prepared data is like this:

shape of `sent_lens` is  `(87716, 200)` and I want to reshape it in a way I can feed it into LSTM.
here `200` stands for the `sequence_lenght` and `87716` is number of samples I have.

below is The code for `LSTM Autoencoder`:

```
inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN,VOCAB_SIZE), name="input")
encoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(LATENT_SIZE), merge_mode="sum", name="encoder_lstm")(inputs)
decoded = RepeatVector(SEQUENCE_LEN, name="repeater")(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(VOCAB_SIZE, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss='mse')
autoencoder.summary()
history = autoencoder.fit(Xtrain, Xtrain,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
epochs=NUM_EPOCHS)
```

Do I still need to do anything extra, if No, why I can not get this works?

Please let me know which part is not clear I will explain.

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: You need an embedding layer to get sequence of  embedding vectors instead  of sequence of token ids, which would make your input always fitting into [batch, seq_length, embedding_dimension]. You would need to truncate or pad to make every sentence always 200 in length though. feel free to update your question after the change.  You could look into pre-trained embeddings like `word2vec`,`Glov` etc.

Comment: @greeness Many thanks for taking the time and answering my question. the shape of data is `(number of samples, sequence_lenght)`.the `200` in the shape is the `sequence_lenght` which I have already padded. why it needs to be fed via having a dim for embedding supposing I dont want to embed it? this `LSTM Autoencoder` has been the most confusing model for me:|, please let me know which part do you want me to update

Comment: If you don't use token embedding, then you must somehow do a one-hot embedding for each token. I mean each word will have a dimension of vocabulary. Each sentence would be setence_length x vocabulary which would be not doable in real world (OOM).  Your current representation of sentence is not understandable by a neural network. think about "ticket" and "tickets" if their token ids are 500 and 700 respectively, what do you expect the network to generalize??

Comment: I have tried with embedding layer as well, in the code is commented, but there again error raises. I did not know how can I reshape my input`(number of samples, sequence_lenght)` into `3d` which we need here. I will include the embedding part I have done.

Comment: after you embed each token into k-dimension, you should have the extra dimension so it becomes 3d.

Comment: I would add that if my input is like this: `inputs = Input(shape=(SEQUENCE_LEN, EMBED_SIZE), name="input")` and the last layer of decoder is like this: `decoded = Bidirectional(LSTM(EMBED_SIZE, return_sequences=True), merge_mode="sum", name="decoder_lstm")(decoded)` then it is working fine. the thing is that I don't want to reconstruct the embedding that's why I need to have `vocab_size` in the last layer of the decoder when I change accordingly to have `vocab_size` in the last layer of decoder then it is not working

Comment: That's what I meant "you need one-hot embedding". see this https://jovianlin.io/keras-one-hot-encode-decode-sequence-data/.  If you convert your training data to one-hot embedding, it should work.

Comment: Can you please have a look at the `update2`. I have already transformed data to numeric version, and I was thinking if I give the numeric data to keras it will take care of the rest, and I just need to do preparation for sequence_lenght .... My confusion especially comes when I can easily run the `autoencoder` over the same data(without doing embedding...). I followed the same step for preparing the data except I did not do any preparation for sequence, padding.... Am I make sense at all?

Comment: Neither of your update1 or udpate2 is not complete. In update 1, you did not show how you use the `embeddings`. you would need to use that `embeddings` as a lookup table to convert the sequence of ids to sequence of embedding vectors. In update2, what you included is an inverse lookup table. I did not see how you convert your list of token ids into list of one-hot vectors.

Comment: I think my whole post was kind of vague, I was not communicating well what I really need. I just updated the whole post. can you please have a look when you had time.

Comment: thanks for the update. I already said this in the first comment. If you need to have the `vocab_size` as the number of neurons in the decoder part, use a one-hot encoding as a transformer to convert your input. For example, if you have two sentences as [[3, 2, 0], [1, 2, 3]] where the vocab_size=4 and sentence_length=3, you should use a one-hot embedding to convert that input into a form like "[[[0,0,0,1], [0,0,1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]], [[0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]]]" so this is shaped 3d. Note [1, 0,0, 0] stands for token 0, [0,1,0,0] stands for token 1, so on and so forth.

Comment: This tf function should be handy: `tf.keras.backend.one_hot(indices=sent_wids, classes=vocab_size)` to do one-hot encoding, do make sure any `wids` is less than your `vocab_size`. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/one_hot

Comment: Thank you so much, I just saw your comment!, I will try this. I do not know why I was thinking Keras will take of this part if we do not mean to use specific embedding.

Comment: I tried to use the one_hot encoding the same way as you said. It raises this error `in check_num_samples
    'you should specify the + steps_name +  argument 
ValueError: If your data is in the form of symbolic tensors, you should specify the steps_per_epoch argument (instead of the batch_size argument, because symbolic tensors are expected to produce batches of input data).` I have searched this error, but could not find a clean way to fix it:|

Comment: I find it really hard to follow your code to be able to help. You could share (if you're allowed to) what prepare_data.clean_and_tokenize(bool) is or, at least, values in the output variables so we can reproduce it somehow. If you cannot provide word2vec_50d_7w file, let us know what is needed from model_wv. Anyway I can create my own np.zeros array. If you can kindly give us those missing parts (with/without details) it's much easier to help you. BTW, it should be tf.keras.backend.one_hot(indices=sent_wids, num_classes=VOCAB_SIZE) since "classes" argument doesn't exist (:

Comment: @jonathan Thank you so much for following with my question. Actually I dont want `w2vec` anymore, I just put it there to say that with `w2vec` it works but without word2vec it does not. I have applied `one_hot encoding` and received the error, please have a look at the end of my question. this is the same code as: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Deep-Learning-with-Keras/blob/master/Chapter07/sent-thoughts-rnn.py I just dont want to follow the embedding part. I want to have the vocab size in the decoder for that I think I have to avoid having the embeddin, correct me if Im wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as said in the comments it turns out I just needed to do `one_hot_encoding`.

when I did one_hot encoding using the tf.keras.backend it throws the error that I have updated in my question.

Then I tried `to_categorical(sent_wids, num_classes=VOCAB_SIZE)` and it fixed (however faced with `memory error` :D which is different story)!!!

I should also mention that I tried `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead of `one_hot_encoding` though it did not work!

Thank you for all your help:)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reshape your data in the following way:

- **Samples**. One sequence is one sample. A batch is comprised of one or
  more samples.
- **Time Steps**. One time step is one point of observation
  in the sample.
- **Features**. One feature is one observation at a time
  step.

`(samples, time_steps, features)`

Then your model should look like the following (simplified version):

```
visible = Input(shape=(time_steps, features))
encoder = LSTM(100, activation='relu')(visible)
# define reconstruct decoder
decoder = RepeatVector(time_steps)(encoder)
decoder = LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(decoder)
decoder = TimeDistributed(Dense(features))(decoder)
model = Model(visible, decoder)
```

Check [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/lstm-autoencoders/) great tutorial. Should be helpful for your case.

**However**, that said you might only need to [expand the dimensions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) of the array.

Check [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-implement-seq2seq-lstm-model-in-keras-shortcutnlp-6f355f3e5639) out as well it might clear things up.

Hope the above is helpful.

Comment: I appreciate you put time and providing me with your answer, though, I know about these concepts and I have read those links before. My question is how can I do that reshaping according to the shape of data I have. I will give it a shot and again look at the links. thanks