# How to sum up a value on specific indices in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice

I have a matrice like this:

```
mat1 = tf.Variable([[0.  0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.7 0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.  0.  0.  0. ]
                   [0.  0.  0.  0. ]])
mat1 = mat1 + abs(mat1)/2
```

Also, an indice matrice like this:

```
prob_indice = tf.constant([[0 1]
                           [0 3]
                           [1 1]
                           [1 2]
                           [1 3]
                           [5 0]
                           [5 1]
                           [5 2]
                           [5 3]
                           [6 1]
                           [6 3]])
energy_allocation = 0.05
```

Now I want to sum up the elements in `mat1` with `energy_allocation` in which indices is in `prob_indice`.

So the expected output would be:

```
                  [[0     0.05    0    0.05   ]
                   [0.7   0.05  0.05    0.05 ]
                   [0.    0.      0.    0.   ]
                   [0.    0.      0.    0.   ]
                   [0.    0.      0.    0.   ]
                   [0.05  0.05   0.05   0.05 ]
                   [0.    0.05   0.     0.05 ]]
```

**Update1**

mat1 has been calculated in this way `mat1 = x + abs(x)/2` thats why if I use the `tf.scatter_nd_add` it raises this error:

> return ref._lazy_read(gen_state_ops.resource_scatter_nd_add(  #
>   pylint: disable=protected-access AttributeError:
>   'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute
>   '_lazy_read'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `tf.scatter_nd_add()`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

mat1 = tf.Variable([[0. ,0. ,0. ,0.],
                    [0.7 ,0. , 0.,  0. ],
                    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 0., 0., 0.],
                    [0., 0., 0., 0.],])

prob_indice = tf.constant([[0 ,1],
                           [0, 3],
                           [1, 1],
                           [1, 2],
                           [1, 3],
                           [5, 0],
                           [5, 1],
                           [5, 2],
                           [5, 3],
                           [6, 1],
                           [6, 3]])
energy_allocation = 0.05
result = tf.scatter_nd_add(mat1,
                           prob_indice,
                           energy_allocation*tf.ones(shape=(prob_indice.shape[0])))

# if your mat1 is tf.Tensor,you can use tf.scatter_nd to achieve it.
# result = tf.scatter_nd(prob_indice,
#                        energy_allocation * tf.ones(shape=(prob_indice.shape[0])),
#                        mat1.shape) + mat1

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(result))

# [[0.   0.05 0.   0.05]
#  [0.7  0.05 0.05 0.05]
#  [0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
#  [0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
#  [0.   0.   0.   0.  ]
#  [0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05]
#  [0.   0.05 0.   0.05]]
```

**Update:**

You can use `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add()` instead of `tf.scatter_nd_add()` in tensorflow `version=2`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. can I ask which version of tensorflow you use? as I got this error `return ref._lazy_read(gen_state_ops.resource_scatter_nd_add(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute _lazy_read` even if `p` is a variable

Comment: @sariii `version=1.12`. What's your `p`?

Comment: Im using `version= 2` which raises this error, when I search the error they saying the tensor should be variable which in my case is true. maybe it is a bug, I will try to check your solution with `version=13`

Comment: @sariii You can try `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` in `version=2`.

Comment: Sounds the problem is with `mat1`. I wanted to access only positive values in my matric, So I did `mat1= (x + tf.abs(x)) / 2` if I feed the `mat1` it raises error but if I give `original matrice` it is running fine. do you have any idea what is the reason here?

Comment: even in your reproducible example, if you change `mat1 = mat1 + abs(mat1)/2` it then raises error

Comment: @sariii  Please distinguish between `tf.Variable` and `tf.Tensor`. `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add` need your data is `tf.Variable`. But `mat1= (x + tf.abs(x)) / 2` will return `tf.Tensor` type even if `mat1` is `tf.Variable`. You can use `mat1 = tf.Variable(mat1)` to solve it.

Comment: @sariii If your `mat1` is `tf.Tensor`,you can also use  `tf.scatter_nd `(updated answer) to achieve it.

Comment: Actually, before posting the question, i was trying to do using `tf.scatter_nd` or even `tf.scatter_nd_update`. I thought I can not do that with `tf.scatter_nd` as only there are two input argument to it( I did not know how to inject the `energy_allocation` into it. and with `tf.scatter_nd_update` it raises an error, so I thought Im in the wrong track:|

Comment: By any chance do you have any idea of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730261/how-to-reshape-text-data-to-be-suitable-for-lstm-model-in-keras.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting its doable with `scatter_nd`. I also did this `result = tf.scatter_nd(prob_indice, energy_allocation * tf.ones(shape=(prob_indice.shape[0])),
                    shape = mat1.shape)
final = result + mat1` and it worked :)